# How do I calculate the dot product between one vector and a list of vectors?

Tags: python, networkx, eigenvector

I have a vector and the Eigenvectors of the matrix H, id like to find the dot product on V1 with every vector in the array.

I want to multiply the vector `PhiZero` with every eigenvector that's calculated for `H`

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import math
import networkx as nx

Alpha = []
n=3
p=0.5
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n,p) 
A = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
w = np.zeros(shape=(n,n))
w[1,2] = 1
gamma = 1/(n*p)
H = (-w) - (gamma * A)
```

ive chosen a random position in w,

```
evals, evecs = la.eig(H)
PhiZero = np.reciprocal(math.sqrt(n)) * np.ones((n,1), dtype=int)
```

i've tried to calculate it two ways, the first way, I get a 3x3 matrix

```
Alpha = np.dot(PhiZero.transpose(), evecs)
```

the other way, I tried it with a `for` loop:

```
for y in evecs:
    alphaJ = np.dot(PhiZero.transpose(), evecs) 
    Alpha.append(alphaJ)
```

i've taken the transpose PhiZero to make the dimensions align with evecs (1x3 & 3x1)

Comment: Can you provide code to generate a typical w? The values shouldn't matter, just the dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second approach, should you not have:

`alphaJ = np.dot(PhiZero.transpose(), y)`

rather than

`alphaJ = np.dot(PhiZero.transpose(), evecs)`
?

If I try your first example, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import math
import networkx as nx

Alpha = []
n=3
p=0.5
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(n,p) 
A = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)
w = np.zeros(shape=(n,n))
w[1,2] = 1
gamma = 1/(n*p)
H = (-w) - (gamma * A)

evals, evecs = la.eig(H)
PhiZero = np.reciprocal(math.sqrt(n)) * np.ones((n,1), dtype=int)

Alpha = np.dot(PhiZero.transpose(), evecs)

print(Alpha)
```

gives

```
[[ 0.95293215 -0.32163376  0.03179978]]
```

Are you sure you get a 3x3 if you run this?

Comment: I think we'd really need to see w and gamma to help further. At present I'm guessing their shape.

Comment: ive added them both, the position of the 1 in w is arbitrary

Comment: See edit to my answer - I get a 1x3 ndarray. Don't you?

Comment: yeah youre right, I was trying to add evecs[i] hoping it would calculate each at a time. Thank you for your time